# Making laptop not increase/decrease screen brightness when changing power source

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, lcd, energy-saving

When I disconnect my laptop from AC power, its screen becomes more dim, in order to save battery. When I connect it back to AC power, it becomes bright, because now it's not concerned with battery level.

I appreciate this logic, but I prefer my laptop stay at the same brightness level regardless of whether it's plugged-in or not. How can I accomplish this?

(I'm using Windows XP.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your power management settings (try Control Panel | Power) or your laptop may have a manufacturer-supplied program to handle this.  Usually these let you create and/or select power management profiles, which can include screen brightness settings.

Comment: I've looked there before asking this question, nothing there.

Comment: In that case, perhaps check with the laptop manufacturer, or mention here what make and model it is; perhaps someone will know how to change the setting.

Comment: It's a Samsung Series 9. The manufacturer's support line told me to look for a power manager program myself, but I don't know any good one that does this, and I hope someone here knows.

Comment: I'm adding a new answer ... take a look there.

Answer (score 2):

My XP laptop is a Lenovo; they do supply a power manager that has quite few more options than XP's control panel.  I had a look in the registry to see what's there and found this:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\PowerCfg\PowerPolicies\11

(the finall number will vary depending on which policy you've chosen, apparently)

Interesting entries (all REG_SZ strings, not DWORDS)

```
DISP_BRTNESS_AC=7
DISP_BRTNESS_DC=1

BRTNESS_WHEN_IDLE_AC=7
BRTNESS_WHEN_IDLE_DC=1

BRTNESS_IDLE_TIMER_AC=0
BRTNESS_IDLE_TIMER_DC=0
```

You might be able to add these entries to your existing profile to get what you're after.

Comment: I tried playing with all of these, but nothing happened.

Comment: That leaves me w/ no more suggestions, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Some laptops have a screen dimming option in the BIOS.  If this option is set to dim on battery, then no amount of fiddling in the OS will turn it off.

I had a Lenovo X61 that did exactly this.  No idea about the Samsung Series 9.  That's a "Designed for Windows 7" laptop, anyway.  While XP may be supported, it might not be supported *well*.

Comment: I searched the BIOS now and found nothing related to screen brightness in there.