# How to disable brightness change when AC power is disconnected? (Linux)

Tags: linux, brightness

On Linux, when laptop is connected to AC power (or disconnected) the screen brightness changes. How can I avoid it?

It's not always brighter with AC. If I increase brightness on battery and then plug in, the screen gets darker. Apparently the last value on AC is restored. So the system remembers two values and switches between them. I'd rather have only one.

I don't know if it is desktop specific. I've had this problem on both XFCE and MATE.

When searching for an answer I've only found [a similar request for Linux Mint](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1286673),
and [the same question on SU but for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/355517/making-laptop-not-increase-decrease-screen-brightness-when-changing-power-source).

Comment: I found this on askubuntu, maybe it's of some help:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/18603/how-to-stop-gnome-power-manager-from-changing-the-global-backlight-setting

Comment: thanks @micwallace, it's helpful. It doesn't work for me, but I'll try to experiment with these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set the same level of brightness when on battery and when on AC power once and you won't notice any change.

Comment: I'm adjusting brightness a few times a day when external light changes. The problem is that I need to change it again after plugging/unplugging.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know.